# three.js directional light following camera

Tags: javascript, three.js

I having a problem with Three.js and lighting following a camera.

I am using orbit control for the mouse movement/

In release number 66 the following use to work

```
    light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 1 );
    light.position = camera.position;
    scene.add(light);
```

However in release number 67 and 68 the lighting doesn't follow the camera. The light is only show on one face.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Some of the Object3D properties have become immutable in r68, so copying to .position directly won't work anymore. Instead you need to use the various methods on these properties:

```
light.position.copy( camera.position );
```

I've not used these lights myself, but from the documentation I gather that they aren't supposed to automatically follow anything. Also, the position is irrelevant since they act like they're an infinite distance away; only the rotation matters.

Comment: see how I did it with the help of above

Comment: Rotation don't matter to directional light as it have no effect at all.
 A common point of confusion for directional lights is that setting the rotation has no effect. This is because three.js's DirectionalLight is the equivalent to what is often called a 'Target Direct Light' in other applications.
read: [DirectionalLight](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/lights/DirectionalLight)

Answer (score 14):

I got it to work with the help of above

```
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);
controls.addEventListener( 'change', light_update );

function light_update()
{
    light.position.copy( camera.position );
}
```

Thanks

Comment: This works for me, however, on first load the object is all black.